# Change color of background android using html color reference

Tags: android, html, layout, colors

I am trying to change the background color of a layout using a html color reference. But i cant seem to make it work.
Here is how i am trying to do it

```
public class FormEngine {

Context context;
RelativeLayout relLayout;

FormEngine(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
    relLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);

}

public void clearScreen(int color) {
    relLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

}
and this is how i am calling this class

```
    FormEngine fEngine = new FormEngine(MainActivity.this);
    setContentView(fEngine.relLayout);
    fEngine.clearScreen(0x708090);
```

Now if i simply try to use Color.Yellow in setBackground color
It works as expected but when i pass a color value like this , it simply shows a white background.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x708090` is a fully transparent color. Try this:

```
fEngine.clearScreen(0xFF708090);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I thought android color would work the way they work in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Android colors use ARGB, so you use 0x00 for the alpha part of the color, which is fully transparent.

Use

```
fEngine.clearScreen(0xff708090);
```

instead.

See [Hex Colors in Android are some times 8 digits. How? What is the difference between #FFFFFF and #FFFFFF00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909896/hex-colors-in-android-are-some-times-8-digits-how/6909935#6909935) for more information.