# Hex color code multiple #

Tags: html, css, coldfusion

While editing some old ColdFusion code I found a `<td>` which has a `bgcolor` property. The value of it was `##89969E`. I copied the code to a HTML file and found out the color was different in ColdFusion.

Now, i noticed the double #, so i removed one and the color was the same. Why does the color change when adding/removing a #?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnPnp/1/)

Comment: The double ## is how to escape any # that you need to send to the browser, inside of `<cfoutput></cfoutput>` tags. Otherwise CF server interprets the # as the beginning of a CF variable, and probably error at undefined variable '89969E'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a basic premise, additional hashes are interpreted as a missing/erroneous value and so replaced with a zero, so `##89969E` becomes `#0089969E`. Note that HEX codes can be as long as 8 digits following a hash (if aRGB), where [the last two refer to transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909896/hex-colors-in-android-are-some-times-8-digits-how)

> Missing digits are treated as 0[...]. An incorrect digit is simply
>   interpreted as 0. For example the values #F0F0F0, F0F0F0, F0F0F, #FxFxFx and FxFxFx are all the same.
>
> When color strings longer than 8 characters or shorter than 4
>   characters are used, things start to get strange.

However there are a lot of nuances - you can find out more about this [here](http://scrappy-do.blogspot.co.uk/2004/08/little-rant-about-microsoft-internet.html), and for some fairly entertaining results this creates, have [a little read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color)