# colors code in android are different

Tags: android, colors

The color white, as far as I know is defined as

```
#ffffff
```

but android defines it this way

```
#ffffffff
```

why the 2 extra f?

Thanks

Comment: 6 hex digits means it's RGB,
8 digits means it's ARGB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hex Colors in Android are some times 8 digits. How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909896/hex-colors-in-android-are-some-times-8-digits-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two places define the **transparency/opacity** of the color.

Here's a correct table of percentages to hex values. E.g. for 50% white you'd use #80FFFFFF.

- 100% — FF
- 95% — F2
- 90% — E6
- 85% — D9
- 80% — CC
- 75% — BF
- 70% — B3
- 65% — A6
- 60% — 99
- 55% — 8C
- 50% — 80
- 45% — 73
- 40% — 66
- 35% — 59
- 30% — 4D
- 25% — 40
- 20% — 33
- 15% — 26
- 10% — 1A
- 5% — 0D
- 0% — 00

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/5352802)

Answer (score 3):

Colour codes are usually defined in either 3, 6, or 8 characters.

```
#FFFFFF
```

means that it is in RGB format. However, you can also have

```
#FFFFFFFF
```

is in ARGB format, which means that the first two characters represent the *alpha* value. In other words, the first two characters represent the opacity.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27813407/4230345) for a Java method to calculate the alpha values.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder is there a formula to calculate the first two characters depending of what opacity I would like to have? amdroid suggest to use 87% for primary text and 54% for secondary text and so on

Comment: @edmond have a look at my answer for the table

Comment: @edmond See my update (look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27813407/4230345)) for a Java method / formula.