# Converting xml integer-array of colors to String Array returns null values - How to convert it to Hex programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I'm trying to convert this list of colors from my `colors.xml` to a Java `String Array`

```
<color name="redditred">#EA0027</color>
    <color name="redditorange">#FF8717</color>
    <color name="redditlime">#94E044</color>
    <color name="redditmint">#0DD3BB</color>
    <color name="redditblue">#24A0ED</color>
    <color name="redditpink">#FF66AC</color>
    <color name="redditgold">#DDBD37</color>
    <color name="redditgrey">#A5A4A4</color>
    <color name="redditsemiblack">#222222</color>
    
    <integer-array name="redditColors">
        <item>@color/redditred</item>
        <item>@color/redditorange</item>
        <item>@color/redditlime</item>
        <item>@color/redditmint</item>
        <item>@color/redditblue</item>
        <item>@color/redditpink</item>
        <item>@color/redditgold</item>
        <item>@color/redditgrey</item>
        <item>@color/redditsemiblack</item>
    </integer-array>
```

I've tried using `getResources` and then getting the `array` from the xml resource file and printing it. It returns the `length` of 17 as expected. However when I print the hex values using `Arrays.toString()`, it gives me an array of null values. What am I doing incorrectly, and how can I get my code to print the Hex colors? eg: `[#EA0027, #FF8717, #94E044, ...... ]`

```
String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.redditColors);
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + colors.length);
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + Arrays.toString(colors));
```

Output:

```
onCreate: 17
onCreate: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Edit:

```
String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.redditColors);
for(int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
   String hexInString = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & colors[i]));
   Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: hex: " + hexInString);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`getIntArray()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIntArray(int)) instead of `getStringArray()` and convert to `Hex` with `Integer.toHexString()`

```
int[] colors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.redditColors);

for (int color : colors) {
    String ColorString = "#" + Integer.toHexString(color);
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Hex Color: " + ColorString);
}
```

Result:

```
2021-01-04 08:22:11.819 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ffea0027
2021-01-04 08:22:11.819 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ffff8717
2021-01-04 08:22:11.820 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ff94e044
2021-01-04 08:22:11.820 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ff0dd3bb
2021-01-04 08:22:11.820 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ff24a0ed
2021-01-04 08:22:11.820 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ffff66ac
2021-01-04 08:22:11.820 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ffddbd37
2021-01-04 08:22:11.820 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ffa5a4a4
2021-01-04 08:22:11.820 32308-32308/com.example.... D/LOG_TAG: Hex Color: #ff222222
```

Comment: This works, but it's adding "ff" in front of each String: ```#ffea0027```, ```#ffff8717```. how would I remove that?

Comment: @WHOATEMYNOODLES The extra 2 digits are used to define the colors transparency .. please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909896/hex-colors-in-android-are-some-times-8-digits-how-what-is-the-difference-betwe)

Answer (score 0):

The color hex values are not Strings. So something like #FFFFFF does not translate to a string  "#FFFFF".

To get the array as you want, you can iterate over the `colors` array and use the following to code to convert each color hex to a String and then store it in a new array.

```
String hexInString = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
```

Comment: The code gives me an error: ```The operator & cannot be applied...``` is ```int color``` each array color? I posted my code in an edit above

Comment: My bad. I missed one thing. You need to use ` getResources().getIntArray(R.array.redditColors);` to get the colors since a color is an integer